# MS Access SQL Syntax Error

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to update a microsoft access database table field from a similar field in a linked table.

Here are my table names:

```
Raw data
sectionroster
```

And here's my query so far:

```
UPDATE [raw data].[current supervisor]
FROM [raw data] 
INNER JOIN [sectionroster] ON [raw data].[associate id]=[sectionroster].[employee number]
SET [raw data].[Current Supervisor] = [sectionroster].[supervisor];
```

It's giving me a syntax error referencing the from clause, and I can't figure out why. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE [raw data].[current supervisor]
SET [raw data].[Current Supervisor] = [sectionroster].[supervisor]
FROM [raw data] 
INNER JOIN [sectionroster] ON [raw data].[associate id]=[sectionroster].[employee number]
```

Comment: No problem. Did it work? If so, please accept the answer so that it helps the others.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! However, its giving me the exact same error! Is it possible that I some how have the relationship wrong between the 2 tables?
I have [raw data].[associate id] directly linked to [sectionroster].[employee number]. and this is the only relationship existing on either table.

Thanks again!
JD

Comment: The query looks about right. I found another question on stack overflow. May be this could help you solve the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/537161/sql-update-woes-in-ms-access-operation-must-use-an-updateable-query

Comment: Thanks again, Vinay! I just figured it out!

Comment: This is what worked for me! 
UPDATE [raw data] 
inner join [sectionroster] 
ON [raw data].[associate id]=[sectionroster].[employee number] 
SET [raw data].[Current Supervisor] = [sectionroster].[supervisor] ;

Comment: Oh damn! Yeah, I missed that, You have to update a table always and not a particular row. Sorry about that.

Comment: This is yet another case that if the QBE were used to generate the SQL, this kind of mistake wouldn't have happened in the first place.