# Make a query updateable

Tags: sql, ms-access

Here is my non-updateable query in MS Access 2007:

```
SELECT [OnlineDirectory].BC_SPEC2 
FROM [OnlineDirectory] INNER JOIN Certifs_ABMS 
    ON [OnlineDirectory].ThisID = Certifs_ABMS.ThisID;
```

---

Both `OnlineDirectory` and `Certifs_ABMS`:

- are local tables with a primary key index.
- have indexes ("duplicates okay") on the field `ThisID`.

The query

- has a recordset type of `dynaset`.
- has no record locks.

These are both updateable:

```
SELECT * FROM [OnlineDirectory] 

SELECT * FROM [Certifs_ABMS]
```

I have reviewed Allen Browne's [famous list of hazards](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-61.html) and none of them apply.  **UPDATE:**  Not true.  See accepted answer.

I got excited about adding `DISTINCTROW` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1713511/122139), but no success.

How can I make this query updateable?

Comment: Is this one updateable? `SELECT o.BC_SPEC2 FROM OnlineDirectory AS o WHERE o.ThisID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ThisID FROM Certifs_ABMS);`

Comment: Yes, that is updateable.  I read about this kind of thing but could not apply.  My *actual* query has two joins, making it kind of like the headache produced by being out of my depth in SQL. Not to complain.

Comment: If 2 fields instead of just `ThisID`, how about an `EXISTS` approach? `SELECT o.BC_SPEC2 FROM OnlineDirectory AS o WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Certifs_ABMS AS c WHERE c.ThisID = o.ThisID AND c.OtherField = o.OtherField);`

Comment: I discovered the "normative" table -- the one not receiving the update -- was able to take a compound primary key (this surprised me, I didn't think the data clean enough).  Now updateable.  I believe the SQL-fu of @HansUp may be viable too, but not sure I am up to testing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Both** OnlineDirectory and Certifs_ABMS have indexes ("**duplicates okay**") on the field ThisID.

This is the problem. At least one side of the INNER JOIN needs a unique index (usually a primary key), or the relation is ambiguous.

(Allen Browne: *- The fields in a JOIN are not indexed correctly: there is no primary key or unique index on the JOINed fields.*)

E.g. if there are in both tables two records each with `ThisID = 77`. How should the records be matched?

If this is a n:m relation, you need a junction table between them.