# Access 2016 - Simple update query gives "Operation must use an updateable query" Error

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update

I'm trying to transfer the `color` field value from the `dress` table to the `purchase` table as I'm changing my DB's structure slightly.

Here's the query, it's simple enough but I keep getting the error.

```
UPDATE purchase
SET purchase.color = (SELECT dress.color
                      FROM dress INNER JOIN purchase
                      ON dress.ID = purchase.dressID);
```

I've also tried without JOIN and putting the condition in the WHERE clause but I get the same error.

```
UPDATE purchase
SET purchase.color = (SELECT dress.color
                      FROM dress, purchase
                      WHERE dress.ID = purchase.dressID);
```

I've also read that this error is sometimes due to the file being "read only" or other issues with permission, I've tried everything but nothing seems to work.

[image: Error I'm getting]

Edit: also tried this but I get "missing operator" error

```
UPDATE purchase
SET purchase.color = dress.color
FROM dress INNER JOIN purchase ON dress.ID = purchase.dressID;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Update woes in MS Access - Operation must use an updateable query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537161/sql-update-woes-in-ms-access-operation-must-use-an-updateable-query)

Comment: Thank you, I was browsing through some threads but this one had the answer, a really weird one at that. I will edit with an answer below. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I think you really want a simple, correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE purchase
    SET color = (SELECT d.color
                 FROM dress as d 
                 WHERE d.ID = purchase.dressID
                );
```

If there might be duplicates in the subquery, try `TOP 1`:

```
UPDATE purchase
    SET color = (SELECT TOP 1 d.color
                 FROM dress as d 
                 WHERE d.ID = purchase.dressID
                );
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response but I actually fixed the problem, if you're curious as to how check my answer above.

Comment: @Daniel . . . Your supposed solution does not do what you expect.  I would suggest you use the versions in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer thanks to the link by Ken White.

This query with the weird keyword 'DISTINCTROW' fixed the problem.

```
UPDATE DISTINCTROW purchase
INNER JOIN dress ON purchase.dressID = dress.ID
SET purchase.color = dress.color;
```

Comment: Have you tried this query without DISTINCTROW? Because the JOIN syntax in your question (3rd try) was wrong - it must be `UPDATE x JOIN y SET x...`, not `UPDATE x SET x... FROM x JOIN y`