# Access SQL: Update list with Max() and Min() values not possible

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've a list of dates: **list_of_dates**.

I want to find the max and min values of each number with this code (#1).

It works how it should, and therefore I get the table **MinMax**

Now I want to update a other list (list_of_things) with these newly acquired values (#2).

However, it is not possible.
I assume it's due to **DISTINCT** and the fact that I always get two rows per number, each with the min and max values. Therefore an update is not possible.
Unfortunately I don't know any other way.

[image: list_of_dates]      [image: MinMax dates sorted]

````
#1
SELECT a.number, b.MaxDateTime, c.MinDateTime
FROM (list_of_dates AS a 

INNER JOIN (
SELECT a.number, MAX(a.dat) AS MaxDateTime 
FROM list_of_dates AS a 
GROUP BY a.number) AS b 
ON a.number = b.number) 

INNER JOIN (SELECT a.number, MIN(a.dat) AS MinDateTime 
FROM list_of_dates AS a 
GROUP BY a.number) AS c 
ON a.number = c.number;


#2
UPDATE list_of_things AS a 
LEFT JOIN MinMax AS b 
ON a.number = b.number 
SET a.latest = b. MaxDateTime, a.ealiest = b.MinDateTime```
````

Comment: An UPDATE action cannot be accomplished when a non-editable query is involved. With or without DISTINCT, period. An aggregate query is a non-editable dataset. Saving aggregate data is usually a bad idea anyway. You can loop through recordset in VBA and UPDATE records with values from recordset. Or save records to a 'temp' table then use that table in UPDATE action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No part of an MS Access `update` query can contain aggregation, else the resulting recordset becomes 'not updateable'.

In your case, the use of the `min` & `max` aggregate functions within the `MinMax` subquery cause the final `update` query to become not updateable.

Whilst it is not always advisable to store aggregated data (in favour of generating an output from transactional data using queries), if you really need to do this, here are two possible methods:

#### 1. Using a Temporary Table to store the Aggregated Result

Run a `select into` query such as the following:

```
select 
    t.number, 
    max(t.dat) as maxdatetime,
    min(t.dat) as mindatetime 
into 
    temptable
from 
    list_of_dates t
group by 
    t.number
```

To generate a temporary table called `temptable`, then run the following `update` query which sources date from this temporary table:

```
update 
    list_of_things t1 inner join temptable t2
    on t1.number = t2.number
set 
    t1.latest = t2.maxdatetime,
    t1.earliest = t2.mindatetime
```

#### 2. Use Domain Aggregate Functions

Since [domain aggregate functions](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Expressions-684295d0-97c2-443c-8e0a-8c6b635bec56#ID0EAABAAA=Domain) (`dcount`, `dsum`, `dmin`, `dmax` etc.) are evaluated separately from the evaluation of the query, they do not break the updateable nature of a query.

As such, you might consider using a query such as:

```
update 
    list_of_things t1
set 
    t1.latest = dmax("dat","list_of_dates","number = " & t1.number),
    t1.earliest = dmin("dat","list_of_dates","number = " & t1.number)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a shot in the dark, but try adding `DistinctRow` as per [SQL Update woes in MS Access - Operation must use an updateable query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537161/sql-update-woes-in-ms-access-operation-must-use-an-updateable-query/1713511#1713511)

Also try using an inner join. If you need to, you can run an update to a null value first for all the records in the query to simulate the effect of the outer join.