# MAX returns NULL

Tags: ms-access, max

I'm a newbie to Access.
I have two tables (Tp and Temp). I want to update a field in the Temp table with the max of that field in the Tp table.
Max([TP]. [QCTNO])   this returns null in an update query, but if I use it in a select query, it returns a value.
TP table

| id | TESTPACKAGE | QC SEND | QCTNO | QC RECIVE | QC RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AG-TP-520-AIR-0001 | 400.08.15 | 320 | 400.08.15 | UPDATE |
| 2 | AG-TP-520-AIRP-0001 | 400.01.24 | 250 | 401.01.28 | UPDATE |
| 3 | AG-TP-538-BUT-0001 | 400.04.14 | 254 | 401.01.28 | UPDATE |
| 4 | AG-TP-538-BUT-0002 | 400.04.14 | 251 | 401.01.28 | UPDATE |
| 5 | AG-TP-538-BUT-0003 | 400.07.05 | 152 | 401.01.28 | ACC |
| 6 | AG-TP-538-BUT-0004 | 400.07.05 | 254 | 401.01.28 | ACC |
| 7 | AG-TP-538-BUT-0005 | 400.05.17 | 245 | 401.01.28 | ACC |
| 8 | AG-TP-538-BUT-0006 | 400.05.17 | 142 | 401.01.28 | ACC |
| 9 | AG-TP-538-BUT-0007 | 401.01.28 | 175 | 401.01.28 | ACC |
| 10 | AG-TP-538-BUT-0008 | 401.01.28 | 198 | 401.01.28 | ACC |
| 11 | AG-TP-501-BUT-0001 | 401.01.28 | 250 | 401.01.28 | Return |
| 12 | AG-TP-537-BUT-0002 | 400.05.17 | 254 | 401.01.28 | Return |
| 13 | AG-TP-502-BUT-0003 | 401.01.28 | 574 | 401.01.28 | Return |
| 14 | AG-TP-502-BUT-0004 | 401.01.28 | 245 | 401.01.28 | Return |
| 15 | AG-TP-502-BUT-0005 | 400.05.17 | 283 | 401.01.28 | Return |
| 16 | AG-TP-502-BUT-0006 | 400.05.17 | 282 | 401.01.28 | Return |
| 17 | AG-TP-502-BUT-0007 | 400.05.17 | 247 | 401.01.28 | Return |

Temp table

| id | TESTPACKAGE | QC SEND | QCTNO | QC RECIVE | QC RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | AG-TP-538-BUT-0007 | 401.01.28 | 175 | 401.01.28 | ACC |
| 10 | AG-TP-538-BUT-0008 | 401.01.28 | 198 | 401.01.28 | ACC |
| 11 | AG-TP-501-BUT-0001 | 401.01.28 | 250 | 401.01.28 | Return |

what I need

| id | TESTPACKAGE | QC SEND | QCTNO | QC RECIVE | QC RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | AG-TP-538-BUT-0007 | 401.01.28 | 574 |  |  |
| 10 | AG-TP-538-BUT-0008 | 401.01.28 | 574 |  |  |
| 11 | AG-TP-501-BUT-0001 | 401.01.28 | 574 |  |  |

Comment: are you running the query properly?  Running update queries in access is a little tricky.  close the update query completely.  Then find the update query in the Side-Bar under queries.  Update queries have a !  Double click the update query.  In short Access doesn't execute update queries in design mode.

Comment: your query does not include the specified expression 'qctranceno' as part of an aggregate function.

Comment: in that case error is telling you QCTRANCENO needs to be summarized.  I would need to see the data to say more.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Why would you duplicate data between tables? Calculate when needed. If it can be calculated for the update, it can be calculated when needed. In fact, I am surprised the query would run at all. An UPDATE action requires the source to be an editable dataset - aggregate queries are not editable. Edit your question to show sample data as text tables, as well as the attempted SQL.

Comment: Could you add the SQL you're using to the question - in the query select the `SQL View` in the drop-down next to the `Run` button.

Comment: SELECT Max([TP].[QCTNO]) AS max_items
FROM TP;            In a select query, it gives me 574. How can I use it to update my Temp table?

Comment: Did you see my earlier comment? Can't do this with an UPDATE action. Also view https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59027287/access-sql-update-list-with-max-and-min-values-not-possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although saving calculated value is strongly discouraged (not recommended) but if you really interested to do it then use domain aggregate function `DMAX()` to update query. Try-

```
UPDATE TempTable SET [QCTNO]=DMAX("[QCTNO]","[TP]");
```