# Attempting to update table data from another table SQL #SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update

I have two tables, one called whoop_data with fields (id, user_id, date, recovery, sleep, strain)
and another called whoop_user with fields (id, name, average_recovery, average_sleep, average_strain)

I'd like to update the whoop_user average data fields using the whoop_data that is logged.  Below are my attempts to do so.

New to SQL - please be kind :)

The code below results in the following table (works as intended):

| name | AVG(recovery) |
| --- | --- |
| Name2 | 39.5 |
| Name1 | 78 |
| Name3 | 49.5 |

```
/*works as intended*/
SELECT name, AVG(recovery) FROM whoop_users JOIN whoop_data
ON whoop_users.id = whoop_data.user_id
GROUP BY name;
```

Both of the attempts below result in the following table:

| Name | average_recovery |
| --- | --- |
| Name1 | 39.5 |
| Name2 | 39.5 |
| Name3 | 39.5 |

I see what is happening, but I don't understand why, how to fix it, or why the statement above DO work as intended and the ones below don't.

```
 /*attempt 1*/
UPDATE whoop_users 
SET 
    average_recovery = (SELECT AVG(recovery)
    FROM whoop_users JOIN whoop_data ON
    whoop_users.id = whoop_data.user_id
    GROUP BY name)
WHERE 
    EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM whoop_data
        WHERE whoop_data.user_id = whoop_users.id );
        
SELECT * FROM whoop_users;
/*attempt 2*/
WITH a AS
(
    SELECT AVG(recovery) as av
    FROM whoop_users JOIN whoop_data 
    ON whoop_users.id = whoop_data.user_id
    GROUP BY name
)
UPDATE whoop_users
SET
    average_recovery = (SELECT av FROM a);
    
SELECT * FROM whoop_users;
```

Comment: Possibly look into this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/7325680/9177810

Answer (score 0):

You must correlate properly the subquery that returns the averages from `whoop_data` (no joins are needed):

```
UPDATE whoop_users AS u
SET (average_recovery, average_sleep, average_strain) = 
    (
      SELECT AVG(d.recovery), AVG(d.sleep) avg_sleep, AVG(d.strain)
      FROM whoop_data AS d 
      WHERE d.user_id = u.id
    );
```

If your version of SQLite is 3.33.0+ you could also use the `UPDATE...FROM` syntax which sometimes performs better:

```
UPDATE whoop_users AS u
SET average_recovery = d.avg_recovery,
    average_sleep = d.avg_sleep,
    average_strain = d.avg_strain
FROM (
  SELECT user_id,
         AVG(recovery) avg_recovery,
         AVG(sleep) avg_sleep,
         AVG(strain) avg_strain
  FROM whoop_data 
  GROUP BY user_id
) AS d
WHERE u.id = d.user_id;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.  I tried both of your suggestions, and both resulted in a syntax error (missing semicolon).  Could this be a difference in syntax requirements between versions?  Again, I'm new to the language so things that *should* be really easy to fix are not right now :(

Comment: I played around with a few things from your first suggestion and got it to work.  Thanks so much!!

Comment: @LProsser_5 you can see here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=08cbb190469503ff19713a11fdeb8814 that the query is syntactically correct.

Comment: @LProsser_5 fine if it worked and don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark.