# Access 2010 VBA - Runtime 3073

Tags: vba, ms-access

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Operation must use an updatable query. (Error 3073) Microsoft Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170578/operation-must-use-an-updatable-query-error-3073-microsoft-access)

I am using the code below:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO calldata([username], [reportnumber], [reportdate], [custconcern], [cc], [as]) " & _
" VALUES('" & Me.cboopenedby & "','" & Report_Number & " ','" & _
Me.txtopenedon & "','" & Me.cboconcern & " ','" & strCustconcernfixtxt & " ','" & strActionfixtxt & "')"
```

And it is working fine in Access 2007 but when given to someone in 2010 they get:

> Runtime Error 3073 - Operation Must Use an Updateable Query

Any ideas?

Comment: I looked at that but since I am not using a WHERE in the statement it is not Jet

Comment: check the types of values you are passing - is `[report_number]` a string?

Comment: Silly question... Is calldata a table or a non-updateable query?