# SQL UPDate same table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I know this has been posted before but I am not sure I have got my head around the logic let aloan trying to get it into to JET Friendly Syntax.

Here is what I am trying to do

I have a bunch of records that relate to documents and I am planning on renaming the documents with GUID's however some records point to the same document here lays the problem.

**Table** 
**ID, LegacyFullPathNme, GUID, isDuplicate**

my code loops through and assigns each record a GUID. then I want to update the Duplicate Documents records with the same GUID

below is my hash at it but doesn't work "Operation must use an updateable Query

```
UPDATE [IO Documents] a
set a.codedFileName = (SELECT B.codedFileName
                       FROM  [IO Documents] b
                       WHERE b.LegacyFullPathName  = a.LegacyFullPathName)
```

Currently use a macro to go throw RBAR

Comment: possible duplicate of [Operation must use an updatable query. (Error 3073) Microsoft Access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170578/operation-must-use-an-updatable-query-error-3073-microsoft-access)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused on why you would do it this way since now your globally unique id column isn't unique in that multiple rows will have it.

I think a better method would be to simply create a new table from your old one with a row for each file path.

```
SELECT LegacyFullPathNme
INTO newtable
FROM oldtable
GROUP BY LegacyFullPathNme;
```

and then add the guid into the new table afterwards. (note that I didn't test that sql snippet so that might not be proper syntax but I think it gets the point across).

Comment: thank you this is really nice solution, and after reading I have no idea how I have made it so overly complex.

Comment: No problem. Sometimes a problem just needs a new set of eyes. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for something like this:

```sql
UPDATE [IO Documents] SET
codedFileName = DMin("codedFileName","IO Documents","LegacyFullPathName='" & LegacyFullPathName & "'")
```