# Get the total number of previous records

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I am creating a query in *MS Access* that needs to update newly created field with the total number of previous records. Something like this:

*Original table:*

```
|  ID | Name |
--------------
|  1  | Mark |
--------------
|  2  | Mich |
--------------
|  3  | Isak |
--------------
```

*Now I add another column ( of type `int` ), e.g. `Ordinal_Number` :*

```
|  ID | Name | Ordinal_Number |
-------------------------------
|  1  | Mark |                |
-------------------------------
|  2  | Mich |                | 
-------------------------------
|  3  | Isak |                | 
-------------------------------
```

*Now I need to fill `Ordinal_Number` with the number of previous records :*

```
|  ID | Name | Ordinal_Number |
-------------------------------
|  1  | Mark |       0        |
-------------------------------
|  2  | Mich |       1        | 
-------------------------------
|  3  | Isac |       2        | 
-------------------------------
```

I couldn't even get the idea how to try fighting this problem so I am asking here.

Comment: Is there a reason why `Ordinal_Number` is not simply `id - 1`?  (Previous comment had `=` rather than `-`.)

Comment: @GordonLinoff: No there isn't. I thought that putting zero will explain my problem better.

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT a.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Original_table WHERE a.ID>=ID) as Ordinal_Number
 FROM Original_table as a
 ORDER BY a.ID
```

For the update:

```
UPDATE Original_table o
set  Ordinal_Number=
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Original_table WHERE o.ID>=ID)
```

or for jet4 version

```
UPDATE Original_table o 
inner join
(SELECT a.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Original_table WHERE a.ID>=ID) as Ordinal_Number
 FROM Original_table as a
 ORDER BY a.ID) newt
on o.ID=newt.ID
Set o.Ordinal_Number=newt.Ordinal_Number
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170578/operation-must-use-an-updatable-query-error-3073-microsoft-access) seems to explain my problem...

Comment: Right, if you are using get4, you cannot execute joint quesries within your update statement

Comment: Just in case, I have edited the quesy with alternative join clause. See if it works. But most likely, the compiler will treat the subquery as related

Comment: you have to add commit at the end of the statement :) i.e., after you execute everything, separately run commit; so that all the changes would be added into the table

Comment: I have tried adding `; commit;` at the end of your query but got errors. What am I doing wrong???

Comment: Character found at the end of SQL statement. I am creating query in *Design View* in MS Access 2007. I have switched to *SQL View* and typed the query.

Comment: Ok. Access does not support several statements in one query. SO, you have to execute one. And then the commit; in a separate query. I suppose, you have already executed the first one. SO, all you need now is to run the commit;

Comment: I do not know how to form the second query. I have tried using transactions but keep getting error *Invalid SQL statement; Expected Select...* Can you help me with this last step? Thank you. Best regards.

Comment: Have you tried using the update type of query in your SQL view?

Answer (score 0):

In order to even begin to talk about getting values from a previous record,
you have to define what "previous" means in the context of your table. For
most purposes, Access treats a table as a "big bag of records", with no
defined order -- most specifically, records are not inherently ordered by
entry sequence. In any situation where you want to talk about "previous" or
"next" records, you must specify a sort order for the records -- for
example, in the ORDER BY clause of a query. And that sort order must be
defined in terms of data in the records.

If you need to process records in order of entry, then you need to have a
date/time field in the records that is set to Now() whenever a record is
entered. If your records have a consecutive autonumber primary key, then In
carefully restricted circumstances, you might use that key field as an
indicator of the entry sequence. However, not all tables use autonumber
keys, and even in those that do, autonumbers can become random, not
consecutive, under certain circumstances. So if you care about entry
sequence, you really ought to use a date/time field to store the
information.

Once you have established a field that you can use to determine the sequence
of records, you don't really need to store the current inventory total in
any record. It can always be calculated on the fly by adding up the
transaction quantities of all records entered up through the current one.
In some cases, it may be useful to store it for efficiency's sake, but that
runs the risk of having inconsistent data if, for example, somebody modifies
one of the earlier records without recalculating the total in all subsequent
records. So I don't recommend storing this calculated data unless you find
you really need to.

Comment: I have autonumber as primary key that starts from 1. The problem is deletion of records. If I delete second record from above, I will have `1` and `3` as ID. Since I need to display the ordinal number of the record I have decided to add a new field and just fill it in with the number of previous records + 1.

Answer (score 0):

The ordinal number starts with `0`, so I would do:

```
update Original
    set Ordinal_Number = (select count(*)
                          from Original as o2 
                          where o2.ID <= original.ID
                         ) - 1;
```

Comment: It didn't work. Let me first clarify things : I am copying this query in MS Access, in query's *SQL View*. After running it, a dialog box pops up prompting me to enter value for `o2.ID`. After I do that the same dialog pops up only this time asks for `o.ID`. After I enter number, I get error *Operation must use an updatable query*, which makes me think that the problem I have is described in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170578/operation-must-use-an-updatable-query-error-3073-microsoft-access?lq=1). Any thoughts on how to fix it? Thank you for replying.