# Access: Update Table from a joint on the same table and a secondary table

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I am trying to update a table using records from the same table and another table but MS ACCESS says my SQL is wrong. I can't understand where the error is, to me it looks ok:

```
UPDATE Clients AS T1

 INNER JOIN

(SELECT DISTINCT 
Clients.ID_Client AS FED, 
Clients.Name, 
SecondTable.Client_Name, 
SecondTable.ABI_Code AS ABI

FROM  SecondTable INNER JOIN Clients ON SecondTable.FieldToUpdate=Clients.Name) AS T2

SET T1.FieldToUpdate = T2.FED
WHERE T1.ABI_Code =T2.ABI
```

It says "Syntax Error" in the Update query and the cursor is on the SET instruction-

Answer (score 0):

Try following query:

```
    UPDATE T1 
        SET T1.FieldToUpdate = T2.FED
    FROM 
        Clients AS T1
    INNER JOIN
        (SELECT DISTINCT 
        Clients.ID_Client AS FED, 
        Clients.Name, 
        SecondTable.Client_Name, 
        SecondTable.ABI_Code AS ABI
        FROM  SecondTable INNER JOIN Clients ON SecondTable.FieldToUpdate=Clients.Name) AS T2
    ON
        T1.ClientID = T2.ClientID
    WHERE 
        T1.ABI_Code =T2.ABI
```

Comment: Since I use an alias for ClientID on T2 I suppose should use:

ON T1.ClientID = T2.FED

but when I run the query now I have an error that translated is something like: "For the operation is necessary a query that can be updated" (!)

Comment: @NicolaPrada can you try removing where and add it to join itself ON T1.ClientID = T2.FED AND T1.ABI_Code =T2.ABI.

Comment: @NicolaPrada can you provide exact error message which you are receiving

Comment: error 3073: "Operation must use an updatable query.". I guess this explain the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170578/operation-must-use-an-updatable-query-error-3073-microsoft-access

Comment: @NicolaPrada what is type of FieldToUpdate in clients and SecondTable and is it primary key?

Comment: type is text and yes, Clients_ID is a primary key

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67216/discussion-between-sandeep-and-nicola-prada).

Comment: I solved using a temporary table. The problem is the Access JET Engine. Thanks.