# Operation must be an updatable query - Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm writing a database and I simply want to update `tblSchedule` with the `ItemNo` from `tblStock` but I get an error when trying to run this:

> Operation must be an updatable query

I can't seem to figure out why it's not working.

```
UPDATE [tblSchedule] 
SET [tblSchedule].ItemNo = 
         (SELECT DISTINCT Item 
          FROM [tblStock], [tblSchedule] 
          WHERE [tblStock].Bookcode=[tblSchedule].[PartCode]
         )`;
```

Any help would really be appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of [Operation must use an updatable query. (Error 3073) Microsoft Access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170578/operation-must-use-an-updatable-query-error-3073-microsoft-access)

Comment: Thanks, I did read that article already but it didn't give a definitive answer, since it was old I posted again to see if there had been any further developments. I think I may have to go down the dlookup route (not that i want to)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing bracket in your SQL.

```
UPDATE [tblSchedule] Set
  [tblSchedule].ItemNo = (
    SELECT DISTINCT Item 
    FROM [tblStock], [tblSchedule  -- Missing closing bracket
    WHERE ((([tblStock].Bookcode)=[tblSchedule].[PartCode]))
  )
```

Try closing the bracket on `tblSchedule`.

I do not have an Access database to test this on for you, though.

Comment: Doesn't look like there's a missing bracket, even in the older edit?

Comment: Apologies this was a typo as I tidied my tables names up for the example (my table name was "tblSchedule-WK30RealDataTest1" which i though was too long for an example). I've corrected this now.

Comment: No problem, @Walshie1987. Sometimes (for me) it is the simple stuff.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your inner SELECT is returning 2 records instead of one.

You can do this to validate.

```
SELECT Items.ItemNo, count(*) total
FROM 
(
   SELECT DISTINCT Sc.ItemNo, St.Item
   FROM 
      [tblSchedule] Sc INNER JOIN
      [tblStock] St ON Sc.PartCode = St.Bookcode
) as Items
GROUP BY Items.ItemNo
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, the output is 252, which I'm guessing is correct as there are 252 records that need updating.

Comment: Maybe i explain wrong. That query should return 0. Otherwise mean you are trying to update ItemNo with two values { value1,  value2 } and that is wrong.

Comment: That `distinct` in your query make me wonder if you mean something like `TOP 1` instead. But without knowing your schema i cant help.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the simplicity of what I wanted I've gone down the Dlookup route which works successfully.

```
UPDATE [tblSchedule], [tblStock] SET [tblSchedule].ItemNo = DLookUp("Item","[tblStock]","[tblStock].Bookcode='" & [tblSchedule].[PartCode] & "'")
WHERE (([tblStock].[Bookcode]=[tblSchedule].[PartCode]));
```

It's probably not the best method but due to the small amount of records it updates (252) it works perfectly without any noticable time delay.

Thanks Again!
Chris