# Access SQL UPDATE statement with HAVING clause

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am having trouble with the update statement below. I keep getting missing semicolon as an error anyone knows correct syntax?

```
Update FactQuote fq 
LEFT JOIN FactQuoteProduct as fqp on fq.spQuoteID=fqp.fk_spQuoteID 
SET fq.spQuoteStatus = 5
WHERE  fq.quoteDate < 5/10/2016
and fq.spQuoteStatus < 4 
and fq.spQuotestatus <>8 
HAVING sum(fqp.ItemTotal)<2000;
```

Comment: Just curious... how can fq.spquotestatus be <4 and <> 8... wouldn't the < 4 suffice?  and last time I used access didn't dates have to be wrapped in #'s?  `Where fq.quoteDate < #5/10/2016#`?

Comment: hahah you are right thx, I changed something forgot to remove that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `DSum()` expression to avoid that *"not updateable"* complaint.

Also notice the second of these 2 conditions is not needed.  When `spQuoteStatus < 4`, it can't be equal to 8, so adding the condition `spQuotestatus <> 8` serves no purpose:

```sql
AND fq.spQuoteStatus < 4
AND fq.spQuotestatus <> 8
```

Assuming `spQuoteStatus` and `fk_spQuoteID` are both numeric datatype ...

```sql
UPDATE FactQuote AS fq 
SET fq.spQuoteStatus = 5
WHERE
        fq.quoteDate < #2016-5-10#
    AND fq.spQuoteStatus < 4 
    AND DSum("ItemTotal", "FactQuoteProduct", "fk_spQuoteID=" & spQuoteID) < 2000;
```

If those fields are text datatype, change the last condition to this ...

```sql
DSum("ItemTotal", "FactQuoteProduct", "fk_spQuoteID='" & spQuoteID & "'") < 2000
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do your aggregation in a subquery since you can't aggregate and do an UPDATE in a single query. Something like:

```
Update FactQuote fq 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT fk_spQuoteID, sum(ItemTotal) as itemTotal FROM FactQuoteProduct GROUP BY fk_spQuoteID) as fqp on fq.spQuoteID=fqp.fk_spQuoteID 
SET fq.spQuoteStatus = 5
WHERE  fq.quoteDate < 5/10/2016
and fq.spQuoteStatus < 4 
and fq.spQuotestatus <>8 
and fqp.itemTotal < 2000
```

Comment: I get operation must use an updateable query with this.can this only work on queries FactQuote is a table in this event

Comment: Access is fickle. [check out these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170578/operation-must-use-an-updatable-query-error-3073-microsoft-access) to see if anything there works. Link tables, saved Update queries, and a few other gotchas that people have work arounds may help out. I believe the syntax here is correct.

Comment: syntax is correct minus renaming itemtotal due to circular reference thx