# VBA Excel - Access Query not updateable

Tags: sql, vba, excel, ms-access

I am getting an error trying to run a query through VBA in Excel.

Error:

> Run-time error '3073':
>   Operation must use an updateable query.

I have a query that is fetching data from one table in Excel.

qryAllData:

```
SELECT ID, Field1 AS [Date], Field9 AS [Alarm Init], Field5 AS [Alarm End], CVDate(Field2) AS [Time]
FROM [Jet Info]
WHERE (Field3 LIKE 'ALARM' OR Field8 LIKE 'ALARM:') AND Field5 NOT LIKE 'Program' AND (Field9 NOT LIKE 'Program' OR ISNULL(Field9));
```

I originally had been directly referencing this query in Excel but was still getting the above error, so I tried referencing the query instead.

qrySelData:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW TOP 1 a.*
FROM [Process Info] AS a, [Complete Data] AS b
WHERE (((a.Date) Not In (SELECT [Date] FROM [Complete Data])) AND ((a.[Start Time]) Not In (SELECT [Start Time] FROM [Complete Data])));
```

Here is my VBA code:

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
     Refresh_Data
     Dim objAccess As Object

     Set objAccess = GetObject("C:\Users\******\Documents\Database21.accdb")

     objAccess.Visible = False

     objAccess.DoCmd.OpenQuery ("qrySelData")

     objAccess.Quit
     Set objAccess = Nothing
 End Sub
```

Running the sub in VBA throws error 3072 on the `objAccess.DoCmd.OpenQuery ("qrySelData")` line.

Any help would be appreciated - if you need more info let me know.

Comment: Looks like the issue is in the join: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170578/operation-must-use-an-updatable-query-error-3073-microsoft-access Some different recommendations here--one is to insert into a temp table then select from it. That seems like it would work for you.

Comment: @JacobH so instead of referencing the query, I should make a dummy table for `qryAllData` to insert into and then reference that with `qrySelData`?

Comment: @JacobH I am still having trouble. So I have a temp table that is being referenced; how do I execute the query that I am using to paste data into the temp table? That seems to be my main issue currently.

Comment: What is your overall goal? You do not mention it anywhere. Classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Don't just tell us your attempted *Y solution*, tell us your *X problem*.

Answer (score 0):

The first query is not updatable because you are using function (cvdate) in select column list. Remove this column or function and it should work.

Second query (seems to be completly different) have missing join condition between `[Process Info]` and `[Complete Data]`. This means Access tries to produce carthesian product and simply have not enough memory...

On first look I would say in second query you should remove `[Complete Data]` from FROM clause (if you anyway don't join those tables).